# semantic entailment, finding a proof

Tags: logic

I was given the assignment to find a proof for the following

$$A, A\rightarrow B, C\rightarrow\lnot B\models\lnot C$$

I understand that when all the hypothesizes of an argument are true, it semantically implies the conclusion. I know how to proof the validity of an argument but have no idea what I am required to do in order to answer the question. What is the solution for the assignment?

Answer (score 1):

You could also argue as follows:

We're given $A$ and $A \rightarrow B$. Hence we know $B$.
 $\neg C = C \rightarrow False$.
Adding $C$ to assumptions, we need to prove $False$.
$\neg B = B \rightarrow False$, yielding $C \rightarrow B \rightarrow False$.

Here we can make $False$ with $C$ and $B$ as $C \rightarrow B \rightarrow False$ = $(C \land B) \rightarrow False$. Using ex falso quodlibet, we can show just about anything - even $False$.

Comment: But this is not a semantic proof.

Comment: @AsafKaragila it isn't?

Comment: It is. All interpretations where $A,A→B,C→¬B$ are evaluated as true, there $C$ is also valued false.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that when all the hypothesizes of an argument are true, it semantically implies the conclusion. I know how to proof the validity of an argument but have no idea what I am required to do in order to answer the question.

Yes, Semantic Entailment means that the *conclusion* will always be valued as true whenever we value *all of the premises* as true.

So, you are required to show that *every* assignment of values for the literals in $\{A,B,C\}$ which holds *all* of the statements in $\{A, A\to B, C\to\lnot B\}$ as true *also* holds the statement in $\{\lnot C\}$ as true.

You begin by noting that the only assignments which values statement $A$ as true will *obviously* be those which hold literal $A$ as true.  So...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to start with an assignment which gives "true" to $A, A\rightarrow B$ and $C\rightarrow\lnot B$, and prove that $\lnot C$ also get assigned the truth value "true".

You can do this using a truth table and consider all the eight assignments to $A,B$ and $C$; then isolate those which give "true" to the three assumptions (hint: there is exactly one like that).

Comment: I constructed the truth table for  A, A→B and C→¬B and found where all three assumptions are true(A-t, B-t, C-f). But what does "prove that C also get assigned the truth value true" mean and maybe you meant ¬C?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Obvious typo... :-)

Comment: Obviously constructing the truth table and finding "true" values isn't enough. How should I present answers for the assignment?

Comment: Well, I don't know how your teachers want you to present the answer. That much depends on whomever is teaching you. So you'll have to ask your TA or professor.

Comment: Constructing truth tables *is* sufficient.  It just becomes *inefficient* when dealing with more literals.

Answer (score 0):

To prove the result would mean to use inference rules rather than a truth table to derive the conclusion.  Here is one way to prove the result using a Fitch-style natural deduction:

[image]

The premises are on the first three lines. On line 4 I use conditional elimination (→E) and reference the conditional on line 2 and the antecedent on line 1. The rule allows me to derive line 4.

I have a rule called modus tollens (MT) in the proof checker and I would like to use that to derive $¬C$ from the third premise and line 4, $B$. However the proof checker requires that $B$ be in the form $¬¬B$. I don't mind these requirements. They force me to follow the permitted inference rules and the proof checker confirms my steps. Besides it is easy to derive $¬¬B$ by deriving a contradiction and using negation introduction (¬I) on line 7.  This allows me to complete the proof on line 8.

There are other ways to write a proof perhaps using different inference rules and different proof checkers. If one follows the rules, assuming they are a complete and sound set of rules, one should be able to derive the goal because the truth table shows that the result is true.

---

If what you are looking for is to show semantic entailment, a [truth table](https://mrieppel.net/prog/truthtable.html) should work:

[image]

Conjoin the premises as implying the conclusion and place this in a truth table generator. This should result in a tautology which is signaled by the column under the implies symbol being true. That is, for all valuations of the atomic sentences, the conditional is true.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Fall 2019. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf

Michael Rieppel, Truth Table Generator https://mrieppel.net/prog/truthtable.html

Comment: That is a proof for *Syntactic* Entailment.

Comment: @GrahamKemp A truth table would give him semantic entailment. As I read his question, he knows how to do that.  He now needs a proof which is a syntactic entailment.